# Hubot misidentifying single user

Tags: hubot, rocket.chat

I've got a Hubot attached to our Rocket.Chat server. We've got a game script for Cards Against Humanity. One day myself and another player joined in at about the same time, and since then, Hubot thinks I am that other player.

Testing this out with the script below, hubot responds with the other user's name and Id, instead of my own (also responds to him and not me):

```
return robot.respond(/who am i(\?)?/ig, function(msg) {
  return msg.reply("*Id: *" + msg.message.user.id + "\n*Name: *" + msg.message.user.name);
});
```

I've attempted stopping the hubot process and redeploying, which does not fix the issue. It seems to persist across all Hubot scripts, as other scripts made since then treat me as the other player.

Is there any way to undo any player mappings that Hubot has made, or any way to "reset" it so this issues goes away? I can't find any documentation on user storage getting out of sync or this issue happening with anyone else.

**EDIT** : I should also mention that the user id and name in the logs and in the console output (when testing manually) shows the correct name and id (my own). It is only incorrect as it is "interpretted" and posted to the channel. I've got no code modifying the message object.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue. We were using a MySQL Hubot Brain adapter. For some reason it overwrote the username in the brain data. Fixed by updating the brain.

Not sure how it did so, considering I can't see any code that updates user names. I'm guessing it's not thread-safe and two calls too close together caused issues.